# Why can't I access the results of a Google Speech request?

Tags: python, google-api, google-speech-api

I want to be able to run several concurrent long recognition jobs at once, so I wrote the following Python code.

```
client = speech.SpeechClient()
config = types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC,
    language_code='en-US')
audio = {"Brooklyn": types.RecognitionAudio(uri='gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac')}
jobs = {}
output = {}

for name, job in audio.items():
  jobs[name] = client.long_running_recognize(config, job)

while len(jobs) > 0:
  time.sleep(5)
  for name, job in jobs.items():
    if job.done() == False:
      print(name + ' progress: ' + str(job.metadata.progress_percent))
    else:
      print(name + ' is done!')
      output[name] = job
      jobs.pop(name)

for name, result in output.items():
  print(u'Transcript: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))
  print('Confidence: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].confidence))
```

It runs fine, but when trying to print the transcript result on the second to last line, I get the error `AttributeError: 'Operation' object has no attribute 'alternatives'`. I think I'm missing something fairly obvious in the way the attributes are nested within the client object, but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized I needed to use `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in the else to figure out what Google was actually returning to me. Turns out I was right, there was some extra nesting I wasn't aware of. `print(u'Transcript: {}'.format(result._result.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript))` did the trick.

Comment: And of course it's worth pointing out that results[0] only gets you the first result. If you have a longer piece of audio than the Brooklyn Bridge example, you're going to need to iterate over the entire results list. Seriously, though, I forgot how powerful PDB is. It's nice to just get to reach in and monkey with things until you find the right solution.